# How can I convert my phone country code to iso2 in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

For example, I have +92 phone code for Pakistan and I want to convert it to iso2( e.g Pakistan's iso2 is 'PK'). So, is there any library to do this? I have tried 'country-code-lookup' but it is giving wrong result.

```
import * as lookup from 'country-code-lookup';
lookup.byIso(parseInt('+92'))
```

It should return an object with iso2 'PK', but it is giving me a wrong result. I have also tried lookup.byIso(parseInt('92'), without + at parameter, but still getting wrong result! Your help would be appreciable! Thanks

Link of country-code-lookup : https://github.com/richorama/country-code-lookup

Comment: What is the result that it is giving you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use React Native Phone Number Input package:

https://reactnativecode.com/react-native-phone-number-input/

Comment: Actually, I'm already using it, and want to define an initial value for the phone input, based on the previous record of user. Let me tell you the whole scenario. I created a screen to update user data. So, I have to map the previous record on screen

Comment: For phoneDefaultCode, I need country iso2 to show the flag